# Teleporting a player from one block to another

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So the problem I have here is I want to teleport a player standing at `1 34 70` to `273 33 -5`.

I have tried using a clock with `testfor @a [x=1.3,y=34,z=70]` hooked up to a `tp @p 273 33 -5` but when I go to `1 34 70` I don't get teleported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see several issues with your setup.

- First of all, there is no need for `testfor` here. The beauty of target selectors is that they work the same in all commands, including `tp`.
- Secondly, there must not be a space between `@a` and the `[]` (the target selector arguments)
- You can specify a radius with your target coordinates in order to make the detection more reliable. I am not sure which value the game assumes by default, but manually setting it to 1 can't hurt.

All things considered, the command you are looking for is simply

```
tp @a[x=1,y=34,z=70,r=1] 273 33 -5
```

or using [4 argument shorthand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments):

```
tp @a[1,34,70,1] 273 33 -5
```

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1:**
You have a space between the selector and the arguments.
Remove that space to make your selector: `@a[x=1.3,y=34,z=70]`

**Problem 2:**
The coordinates in selectors cannot be decimals. As you are looking for someone at 1, 34, 70, just use those coordinates: `@a[x=1,y=34,z=70]`

**Problem 3:**
You are testing if someone is at 1, 34, 70, and then if there is, teleporting **the nearest player to the command block** to 273, 33, -5. What you actually want to do is teleport the person at 1, 34, 70 to 273, 33, -5. You should put the selector arguments into the `tp` command.

**Problem 4:**
There's no radius specified. You need to specify a radius from that point to test for. I'd recommend either a radius of 0 if you want to test just that block.

Fixing this should give you a working command:

```
tp @a[x=1,y=34,z=70,r=0] 273 33 -5
```

You could also compact this down into:

```
tp @a[1,34,70,0] 273 33 -5
```

Here is the wiki page on commands, which may be useful to read up on:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands

Comment: beat me by 21 seconds